# wildcard in URL for webdriver

Tags: java, url, webdriver, wildcard

Hi i have a small problem with URL, i need to verify PDF file, which i must first download. I use this code below:

```
    URL TestURL2 = new URL("file:///C:/Users/Ludek/Downloads/katalog_dokument_53766_test.pdf");
    BufferedInputStream TestFile = new BufferedInputStream(TestURL2.openStream());
    PDFParser TestPDF2 = new PDFParser(TestFile);
    TestPDF2.parse();
    String TestText2 = new PDFTextStripper().getText(TestPDF2.getPDDocument());
    try {
        assertTrue(TestText2.contains("Text PDF"));
        System.out.println("it's  OK");
    } catch (Error e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
        System.out.println("not OK!!!");
    }
```

But numbers 53766 in file name are everytime different. Can i use some wildcard or something else?
Can anyone advise me please? Thanks

Comment: Is it required to use an ``URL`` instead of a simple ``File`` object? If not, scan the files in the parent directory and filter (e.g. with a regex pattern)

Comment: If you don't know the URL, how do you expect the browser to get it?  That's like me telling you to call me, but not giving you my phone number. This question has nothing to do with webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one file in your folder - your pdf, you can use a code similar to this one:

```
 string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/Users/Ludek/Downloads/", "*.pdf");
```

Before the download process, you can always delete all files from the folder or even always specify  a unique download folder, this way only your file will be there and you can be sure when you verify it.

Comment: Thanks, it was great idea

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solved your problem, can you please mark the question as resolution. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution, it's simple and works.

```
  File f = new File("C:/Users/Ludek/Downloads/");
        FilenameFilter textFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf");
            }
        };
        File[] files = f.listFiles(textFilter);
        for (File file : files) {
            String URL =  file.getCanonicalPath().substring(25);
            URL TestURL2 = new URL("file:C:/Users/Ludek/Downloads/" + URL);
```